# Header in get. Angular 6

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-httpclient

I'm doing an example that I've taken from this same web, but I do not know what I'm doing wrong that gives me an error, and even though I look at it I do not see what I'm doing wrong.

When doing "response => response.json()" I get the following error:

> The `json` property does not exist in the `Object` type

My service is as follows:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpHeaders,HttpClient  } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CompetenceService {

  public url: string;

  constructor(private httpCliente: HttpClient) {}

  public createUser(): Observable < any > {
    const getHeaders: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    });
    return this.httpCliente
      .get('http://xxx/xxx/xxx', {
        headers: getHeaders
      }).pipe(
        map(
          response => response.json() < --error: The 'json'
          property does not exist in the 'Object'
          type
        )
      );
  }
}
```

Someone sees that I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to `map` it as you're using `HttpClient`. It is only required in case you're using `Http` from `@angular/http`

`HttpClient` gives you the actual Response Data. So you don't have to call `json` on the response to get the actual data as you had to do in case of using `Http`. And if you do, since there won't be a method named `json` on the response data, it will throw an error. And that's what it has done.

Get rid of it and you should just be fine.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpHeaders, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CompetenceService {

  public url: string;

  constructor(private httpCliente: HttpClient) {}

  public createUser(): Observable < any > {
    const getHeaders: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    });
    return this.httpCliente
      .get('http://xxx/xxx/xxx', {
        headers: getHeaders
      });
  }
}
```